# Pass variable in list and expect its literal value

Tags: tcl

I was trying to write a simple script where I create a list out of some existing variable and when I print the same expect its literal value:

```
set testString "John A. Smith, Mobile:001-445-4567-0987, Pin-556789"
set results  { address contact $testString }
puts $results
```

But I get the below output:

```
address contact $testString
```

Where I was expecting - how can I achieve the same:

```
address contact John A. Smith, Mobile:001-445-4567-0987, Pin-556789
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Braces prevent substitution of variables, so use double quotes instead:

```
set results " address contact $testString "
puts $results
#  address contact John A. Smith, Mobile:001-445-4567-0987, Pin-556789
```

Or use [`subst`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/subst.htm) to force the substitution afterwards:

```
set results { address contact $testString }
set results [subst $results]
puts $results
#  address contact John A. Smith, Mobile:001-445-4567-0987, Pin-556789
```

Or if you actually mean to have a list where the first element is `address`, the second `contact` and the third being `$testString`'s value, then you can use [`list`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm), except the output will look different:

```
set results [list address contact $testString]
puts $results
# address contact {John A. Smith, Mobile:001-445-4567-0987, Pin-556789}
```

But that way, you can get `testString` back if you do something like `lindex $results 2`, whereas if you used any of the earlier methods, you would get only the first word of `testString`, that is, `John`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
set results  { address contact $testString }
```

you are creating a *literal string* (without substitutions) and assigning it to a variable. This is what `{…}` does; it's just like `'single quotes'` in Unix shells except for being nestable.

To get a substitution in there, you either use `"`double quotes`"`, or to run the literal string through the `subst` command:

```
set results " address contact $testString "
```

```
set results [subst { address contact $testString }]
```